# Question about some aspect of Zariski topology

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

In the Folland book "real analysis", in the page 117 is written about Zariski topology: Let $k$ be a field and let $k(X_1,...,X_n)$ be the ring of polynomials in $n$ variables over $k$. Each $P$ from $k(X_1,...,X_n)$ determines a polynomial map $p:k^n \to k$ by substituting elements of $k$ for the formal indeterminates $X_1,...,X_n$. The correspondence $P \to p$ is one-to-one precisely when $k$ is infinite.

As I understand if $k$ is finite, then the correspondence is not one-to-one. I am not sure that for me that sentence is clear. Please help me.

Comment: The function $x\mapsto x^p$ is the identity on $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: What is not clear, exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example: if $k=\mathbb F_2$ (the field with two elements), then $x^2-x$ is a polynomial with degree $2$; in particular, it is not the null polynomial. But the *polynomial function*$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb F_2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb F_2\\x&\mapsto&x^2-x\end{array}$$*is* the null function.

More generally, if $k$ is a finite field whose elements are $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, then $(x-a_1)\times\cdots\times(x-a_n)$ is not the null polynomial, but the polynomial function associated with it *is* the null function.

Comment: Thanks.. And if k is infinite, how formally prove that P->p is one-to-one?

Comment: That is the result of mine theorem of algebra about zeros of polynoms. Am I right?

Comment: To simplify, let us suppose that $n=1$. If $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are two polynomial functions which are identical, then $(p-q)(x)=0$ for every $x\in k$. So, every $x\in k$ is a root if $p(x)-q(x)$. But the only polynomial with infinitely many roots is the null polynomial.

Comment: Yes, and the final step is the result of the main theorem of algebra, yes?

Comment: I am confused. Which final step?

Comment: I mean, the fact that only polynomial with infinite many roots is the null polynomial is the result of main theorem of algebra .. but i understand that this is obvious..thank a lot

Comment: Sorry. Can you tell me a hint, how to prove that for several variables?

Answer (score 1):

For example, if $k=\mathbb{F} _2$, the polynomials $X$ and $X^2$ determine the same function $k\to k$.